# Find all with related objectId name in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

I have a API which finds all data in a table, but inside that table i have an object ID reference to a user.

Table 1 - Story |
Table 2 - User

```
api.get('/all_stories', function(req, res) {
    Story.find({}, function(err, stories) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
            return;
        }
        res.json(stories);
    });
});
```

So this api obviously retrieve all the the data inside Story table and return it as json.

```
creator: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
content: String,
created: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }
```

How do a use ref: 'User' to find and display other data colum inside User table.
Or maybe so return it as json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use `populate` to do this:

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.8.x/docs/populate.html

```
Story
.find({})
.populate('creator')
.exec(function (err, stories) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
            return;
        }
        //stories now contains an array of Story, with their creator property populated with the user document
        res.json(stories);
})
```

It seems you're using the same / very similar model to the example in the docs...

Comment: Wow thank you. I been trying to search for something like that but i didnt know how to word it.